# deviceready did not fire within 5000ms - ionic Native with onesignal

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3, onesignal

I am using one signal plugin for push notification.

First i installed the one signal plugin.

```
ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin
npm install --save @ionic-native/onesignal
```

Here is my code

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.oneSignal.getIds().then((ids)=>{
          console.log("USER ID");
          console.log(ids.userId);
        }).catch((e)=>{
          console.log("error")
          console.log(e);
        })
    })
```

But does not get app id.why?

The error is `plugin_not_installed`.

I remove this plugin again added.

But still get the same error. and also getting this type of err.

```
Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire within 5000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them.

Native: deviceready did not fire within 5000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them.
```

Kindly advice me,

Thanks.

Comment: Are you testing that on a physical device / emulator, right?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I am trying in device.